# PHP or Apache Delete Files

Tags: php, apache, http, centos, delete-file

I have an asterisk server that is placing call recordings in the /var/spool/asterisk/monitor directory. I have managed to get Apache (httpd) to display a list of everything in this directory.

I have a secondary process that is coming along and downloading those recordings and doing something with them. When that process is done I want it to be able to DELETE the recording it pulled.

If I have to use PHP I can, but I have already tried that and do not know enough to get it to work. I am trying the code below, I'm guessing its a permissions issue or something, but I don't know how to change the apache user to run  as a higher level user (root would be fine, and yes I'm aware of the ramifications).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

        if($_GET['action'] == 'delete')
        {
                $myfile = $_GET['filename'];
                $path = getcwd();
                echo($path . "/" . $myfile);
                if(unlink($path . "/" . $myfile))
                {
                        echo('Success!!!');
                }
                else
                {
                        echo('Failure');
                }
        }
        else
        {
                echo('doing nothing');
        }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The other option that I would be ok with would be the ability to do a HTTP DELETE verb against the file and let Apache handle it, but I can't find a good article on how to set that up either.

This is the entry I have in httpd.conf file

```
Alias /recordings "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor"
<Directory "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Next to a `GET` request to retrieve the file, you could do a `DELETE` request to delete the file.

By default, Apache has not request handler for the `DELETE` method, but you can create your own `delete.php` that takes care of the `DELETE` requests:

```
<?php
/**
 * delete script
 */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'DELETE') {
    header('Method not allowed', 405);
    exit;
}
$basepath = __DIR__;
$file = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $basepath . '/' . $file;
$exists = file_exists($path);
if (!$exists) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 204 No Content'); // HTTP/1.1 ...
    exit;
}
$success = unlink($path);
if ($success) {
    printf("Deleted %s\n", $file);
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error');
}
```

In your `.htaccess` file you then map all `DELETE` requests to your deletion script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =DELETE [NC]
RewriteRule .* delete.php
```

The benefit of such a script is, that it correctly communicates the success or failure via the HTTP status codes which are defined: [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 (RFC2616) Section 9.7 DELETE](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7).

Answer (score 0):

Why you are putting `"\\"`  ? the path will not have that double slash is it!

unlink is pretty staright forward

For confirming the path is correct ..  try to open the file using fopen . if it works . delete it with unlink

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

check file exist and delete it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Check file permission and your privileges to delete

http://us.php.net/fileperms

Comment: I changed it to a '/' and it still gives me a false on the unlink() command. The php file is in the same directory as all the wav files I want to work with

Comment: then / also not needed just give file name as the file to bedeleted and php in same folder

Comment: did you try fopen and try to add or print some contetn

Comment: once I do the $file = fopen($myfile) how do I print the contents... I feel so retarded right now lol

Comment: check the answer -- yu can try file-exist

Comment: $file = file_get_contents($myfile) allowed me to get the contents

Comment: atlast waht about the permission . do you have enough privilege to dlete

Comment: I don't know... How can I check what permissions php/apache have?